# PHP 7.1 on IIS Win Server 2012 does not work completely

Tags: php, windows, iis, server

I installed PHP 7.1 on a Windows 2012 Server R2 on IIS.
What did i do?

- installed IIS over ServerManager with CGI
- downloaded PHP 7.1.19 nts (non thread safe)
- unpack it into C:\php\
- Set envirounment variable to PATH=C:\php;
- Add Module Mapping in IIS

I'm created a phpinfo(); File.

But my configuration look like this:
- Configuration File (php.ini) Path = C:\Windows;
- Loaded Configuration File = C:\php\php.ini

If i'm change any settings in c:\php\php.ini, my configuration does not change.

Why is my configuration file located in c:\windows?

Comment: What is the output of this simple php script <?php echo phpinfo()?> in section "Configuration File (php.ini) Path"?

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path = C:\Windows; Loaded Configuration File = C:\php\php.ini;

Comment: Your default configuration path is C:\Windows. And loaded configuration file is C:\php\php.ini. What settings are wrong? And have you restart IIS or at least Application Pool?

Comment: Iam added extension=php_mysqli.dll in php.ini and restarted IIS. But its not in my phpinfo() script and mysqladmin does not work

Comment: Set extension_dir="C:\php\ext" in c:\php\php.ini. This may help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php#install.pecl.windows.problemsolving